# ajax.dataSrc for datatables not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to use dataSrc property or manipulation method for table data. 
To see how I can manipulate data, I am trying this simple code.

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>  
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>  

      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered">  
                     <thead>  
                          <tr>  
                               <th>Mobile</th>  
                               <th>Name</th>  
                               <th>Email</th>
                               <th>Credits</th>
                          </tr>  
                     </thead>  
                </table>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
  <script>  

 $(document).ready(function(){  

      $('#data-table').DataTable({  

           "ajax"     :     {
             "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                var array = {};
                  for ( var i=0, ien=json.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                    array[i] = json[i];//'<a href="/message/'+json[i][0]+'>View message</a>';
                  }
                  console.log(json);
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
                return (JSON.stringify(json));
              }
            },  

           "columns"     :     [  

                {     "data"     :     "Mobile",
                 "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"},  

                {     "data"     :     "Name",
                 "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"},  

                {     "data"     :     "Email",
                 "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"},

                {     "data"     :     "Credits", 
                 "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"},

           ]  
      });  
 }); 
 </script>
```

When I run, localhost/test.php

```
Mobile  Name    Email   Credits 
Not set Not set Not set Not set 
Not set Not set Not set Not set 
Not set Not set Not set Not set
```

Though, data.json has:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "Mobile": "1234567890",
        "Name": "test",
        "Email": "test@gmail.com",
        "Credits": "50",
    }, {
        "Mobile": "8200469963",
        "Name": "amit",
        "Email": "adsf@gmail.com",
        "Credits": "0",
    }, {
        "Mobile": "8989899889",
        "Name": "sdfsd",
        "Email": "sdfsd",
        "Credits": "100",
    }, {
        "Mobile": "9889812580",
        "Name": "box",
        "Email": "asdfadfs@gmail.com",
        "Credits": "98",

    }, {
        "Mobile": "9999999999",
        "Name": "user9",
        "Email": "user9@gmail.com",
        "Credits": "0",
    }]
}
```

Also, If I remove dataSrc part totally. I get Proper results. What am I doing wrong in dataSrc?

Answer (score 2):

When you remove the dataSrc component you are setting it to read the data as an array. You're just not specifying the data object you need to use `json.data` instead of just `json`.

```
$('#data-table').dataTable( {
    "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
        for ( var i=0, ien=json.data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
            json.data[i][0] = '<a href="/message/'+json.data[i][0]+'>View message</a>';
        }
        return json.data;
     }
   }
} );
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `dataSrc` if you need just to create links for email addresses. Remove `dataSrc` and use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option instead.